# Is it possible to make `foldrRanges` as fast as `foldrRange2D`?

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell

This:

```
foldrRange :: (Int -> t -> t) -> t -> Int -> Int -> t
foldrRange cons nil a b = foldr cons nil [a..b-1]
```

Defines a function that folds over a list from `a` til `b`. This:

```
foldrRange :: (Int -> t -> t) -> t -> Int -> Int -> t
foldrRange cons nil a b = go (b-1) nil where
    go b !r | b < a     = r
            | otherwise = go (b-1) (cons b r)
{-# INLINE foldrRange #-}
```

is a ~50x faster version due to proper strictness usage (we know the last element, so we can roll like `foldl'`).

This:

```
foldrRange2D cons nil (ax,ay) (bx,by) 
    = foldr cons nil 
    $ do
        y <- [ay..by-1]
        x <- [ax..bx-1]
        return (x,y)
```

Is a `2D` version of `foldrRange`, i.e., it works over 2D rectangles so that `foldrRange2d (:) [] (0,0) (2,2) == [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)]`. This:

```
foldrRange2D :: ((Int,Int) -> t -> t) -> t -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> t
foldrRange2D cons nil (ax,ay) (bx,by) = go (by-1) nil where
    go by !r 
        | by < ay   = r
        | otherwise = go (by-1) (foldrRange (\ ax -> cons (ax,by)) r ax bx)
```

Is, again, an ~50x faster definition due to better strictness usage. Writing `foldrRange3D`, `foldrRange4D`, etc., would be cumbersome, so one can generalize it like so:

```
foldrRangeND :: forall t . ([Int] -> t -> t) -> t -> [Int] -> [Int] -> t
foldrRangeND cons nil as bs = foldr co ni (zip as bs) [] nil where
    co (a,b) tail lis = foldrRange (\ h t -> tail (h:lis) . t) id a b
    ni lis            = cons lis
```

Unfortunately this definition is at around 120 times slower than `foldrRange2D`, as one can verify with this test:

```
main = do
    let n = 2000
    print $ foldrRange2D (\ (a,b) c -> a+b+c) 0 (0,0) (n,n)
    print $ foldrRanges  (\ [a,b] c -> a+b+c) 0 [0,0] [n,n]
```

I could probably use `ST` to get a faster `foldrRanges`, but is it possible to do so with recursion alone?

Comment: What if you reverse the ranges as before and use `foldl'` with `flip`? You can probably expect a bit of slowdown because GHC can't analyze lists as well as tuples, but it shouldn't be horrible.

Comment: I've tried using `foldl'` before asking, but it didn't improve anything.

Comment: Hmmm. Your code's a bit hard for me to understand. Can you make the grid by right-folding `liftA2 (:)` or similar? That might make it easier to think about.

Comment: I didn't understand, where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an efficient implementation of your algorithm which is inductive on the *dimension* of the input. Fortunately, you can do that in Haskell!

First, replace lists with type level `Nat` indexed vectors. This gives us a type to do induction on (it could probably be done with lists ... but this is much safer).

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

infixl 5 :<
data Vec (n :: Nat) (a :: *) where 
  Nil :: Vec Z a 
  (:<) :: Vec n a -> a -> Vec (S n) a 

instance Functor (Vec n) where 
  fmap _ Nil = Nil 
  fmap f (xs :< x) = fmap f xs :< f x
```

Then your desired function is just the same as the 2D case - just generalize the recursive call:

```
{-# INLINE foldrRangeN #-}
foldrRangeN :: (Vec n Int -> t -> t) -> t -> Vec n Int -> Vec n Int -> t 
foldrRangeN f x Nil Nil = f Nil x 
foldrRangeN cons nil (ax :< ay) (bx :< by) = go (by-1) nil where
    go by !r 
        | by < ay   = r
        | otherwise = go (by-1) (foldrRangeN (\ ax -> cons (ax :< by)) r ax bx)
```

Although when I tested the performance, I was disappointed to see it couldn't keep up with the 2D version. The trick seems to be more inlining. By putting the function in a class, you can get it to inline at each 'dimension' (there must be a better way to do this...)

```
class FoldrRange n where 
  foldrRangeN' :: (Vec n Int -> t -> t) -> t -> Vec n Int -> Vec n Int -> t 

instance FoldrRange Z where
  {-# INLINE foldrRangeN' #-}
  foldrRangeN' f x Nil Nil = f Nil x 

instance FoldrRange n => FoldrRange (S n) where 
  {-# INLINE foldrRangeN' #-}
  foldrRangeN' cons nil (ax :< ay) (bx :< by) = go (by-1) nil where
      go by !r 
          | by < ay   = r
          | otherwise = go (by-1) (foldrRangeN' (\ ax -> cons (ax :< by)) r ax bx)
```

Tested as follows:

```
main = do
  i:n':_ <- getArgs 
  let n = read n' :: Int 
      rs = [ foldrRange2D (\ (a,b) c -> a+b+c) 0 (0,0) (n,n)
           , foldrRangeND (\ [a,b] c -> a+b+c) 0 [0,0] [n,n]
           , foldrRangeN  (\ (Nil :< a :< b) c -> a+b+c) 0 (Nil :< 0 :< 0) (Nil :< n :< n)
           , foldrRangeN' (\ (Nil :< a :< b) c -> a+b+c) 0 (Nil :< 0 :< 0) (Nil :< n :< n)
           ]
  print $ rs !! read i
```

and the results on my system

```
./test 0 4000 +RTS -s : 0.02s
./test 1 4000 +RTS -s : 7.63s
./test 2 4000 +RTS -s : 0.59s
./test 3 4000 +RTS -s : 0.03s
```

Comment: Using class specialization to unroll loops is a well-known trick. I don't think there's a good reason to think there's a better way.

Comment: Oh. It should've been so obvious how to generalize `foldRange2D`. Nether less, I love every bit about this answer. Thank you both. I guess I couldn't apply the inlining trick if I used common lists, correct? I wonder if there is a featured library on Hackage for the dependent vector type.

Comment: @dfeuer I would like to be able to put 'INLINE' on a local function, but it doesn't seem that's possible. Semantically, this would mean that GHC would try to inline that function, but only if it had already decided it was inlining the outer function.